# How can add two blanks between sum and its expression?

Tags: math-operators

The simple latex sum expression:

```
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}  \frac{1}{(1+x)^i} = 100
```

It create the below formulas:

[image]

How can add two blanks between sum and its expression such as below?

[image]

Comment: `\;` or `\hspace{3cm}` or ... (athough the expression is very hard to read if the space after the sum is larger than te hepace around the =) (you very rarely need `\limits` that is the default for sum in display math)

Comment: What would be the reason, other than making the expression harder to interpret?

Comment: I could see wanting to do this if the previous (or subsequent) line were `\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{2i}{2i}\frac{1}{(1+x)^i}=100` and you wanted to emphasize the parts that were remaining the same.  But in that case (1) it would have been much better to get that context from showkey, and (2) `\hphantom` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I often use in math mode `\mkern` which is more flexible and suitable in many circumstances.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\sum_{i=0}^{n}\mkern20mu \frac{1}{(1+x)^i} = 100\]
\[\sum_{i=0}^{n}\qquad \frac{1}{(1+x)^i} = 100\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fittest distance in my os is 0.25cm.

```
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \hspace{0.25cm} \frac{1}{(1+x)^i} = 100
```

Comment: why would you do this though? it is usually better to avoid all explicit spacing as it makes the expressions very hard to adapt to changes in document style or conversion to other formats. Also as noted in comments `\limits` isn't needed here either. Your Operating system is not relevant here TeX will give the same output on all platforms.

Comment: In other words – normally LaTeX has a *very good* idea of what's the best spacing, you should not mess with it unless you're very sure.

Answer (score -1):

To make the blanks you need

```
\hspace*{2cm}
```

Comment: It is `\hspace{2cm}`.

Comment: `2cm` is a lot bigger than the space indicated in the question (unless a very large font os being used)